# jQuery-Ui Multiple instance not working properly with slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 3 sliders with me as `red,green,blue` - i stored the `ui` function in to the function.

i am calling 3 times with different paramenters, but the value always update in to the first(red) instance only.

`blue,green` input values not changing instead `red` updates always. how to make multiple instance if i am wrong?

here is my code :

```
var RGBHanlder = function (container,element) {
              var newContainer = container,
                  colorBar = container.find('.'+element),
                  input = colorBar.prev('input');

                  console.log(input.get(0)); //i have 3 inputs separately.

                $( colorBar ).slider({
                  slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    input.val(setValueInRange.call($this, (ui.value << 0) + 1, 0, 255));
                    color.val('r', ui.value*2.55, input); //always updates red
                  }
                });
          };

          RGBHanlder($('.tbody:first'),'redBar');
          RGBHanlder($('.tbody:first'),'blueBar');
          RGBHanlder($('.tbody:first'),'greenBar');
```

**Update**

I am getting 3 slider working. but the issue with `input` element only.

Comment: Where do `$this` and `color` come from?

Comment: statically i am passing the color (which is the class name) `$this` i am not declare anywhere..